# With LogOff record in database and deleting cookie behind the Session_End ( ) in Global.asax

Tags: c#, cookies, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, session-timeout

I am needing help in a project I'm breaking my head for two days. I am using Microsoft C # MVC5 technology and framework 4.5, also use Entity Framework 6 with Repository Pattern, Unit of Work and Unity for the realization of dependency injection.

I have a controller called AccountController that is responsible for performing the login and logoff user on the system, the controller receives the methods of the repository by applying dependency injection by the same Construtor.

### AccountController

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{

private readonly IUsuarioApp _usuarioApp;
private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWorkAsync;

public AccountController() { }

public AccountController(IUsuarioApp usuarioApp, IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWorkAsync)
{
    _unitOfWorkAsync = unitOfWorkAsync;
    _usuarioApp = usuarioApp;
}

// GET: Login
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Email, Password")]LoginViewModel model,    string returnUrl)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);

        var usuarioAutenticado = _usuarioApp.AutenticarUsuarioPor(model.Email, model.Password);

        var logDeAcesso = new LogDeAcesso { DataDeAcesso = DateTime.Now, UsuarioId = usuarioAutenticado.Id };

        usuarioAutenticado.DataDoUltimoAcesso = logDeAcesso.DataDeAcesso;

        _usuarioApp.Update(usuarioAutenticado);
        _usuarioApp.GetRepository<LogDeAcesso>().Insert(logDeAcesso);
        _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();

        SessionContext.SetAuthenticationToken(usuarioAutenticado.Id.ToString(), false, ConvertToUsuarioViewModel(usuarioAutenticado));
    
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentativa de login inválido.");
        return View(model);
    }
}

public ActionResult LogOff(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado = _usuarioApp.GetRepository<LogDeAcesso>().Query(model => model.UsuarioId == id).OrderBy(model => model.OrderByDescending(c => c.DataDeAcesso)).Select().FirstOrDefault();

        if (ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado == null || ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado.DataDeSaida != DateTime.MinValue) throw new Exception("Erro ao tentar deslogar do sistema.");

        ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado.DataDeSaida = DateTime.Now;
        _usuarioApp.GetRepository<LogDeAcesso>().Update(ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado);
        _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Clear(); //Pode não ser necessário, mas não é problemático o uso como prevenção
        Session.Abandon();

        //Limpar o cookie de Autenticação
        var resetFormsCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        resetFormsCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(resetFormsCookie);

        //Limpar a session cookie
        var resetSessionCookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        resetSessionCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(resetSessionCookie);

        //Invalida o Cache no lado do Cliente
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Danger("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}


#region Helpers

private UsuarioViewModel ConvertToUsuarioViewModel(Usuario usuario)
{
    return new UsuarioViewModel
    {
        Id = usuario.Id,
        Nome = usuario.Nome,
        UltimoAcesso = usuario.DataDoUltimoAcesso
    };
}

#endregion

}
```

Is seen as the login, the user is authenticated via email and the password is created an instance of the Access Log is registered where the entry access and is subsequently created the cookie will be stored where the cookie will allow the access Application pages.

After obtaining access, the user can click the logoff button, which launches the ActionResult LogOff method that will get the last log created access based on the user id, update the data with the DataDeSaida LogDeAcesso, clear the Session and Cookies, redirecting it to the Login page. From there he will only have access again the other pages if he perform the login again.

Is dynamic works very well, but has a problem, and if the user does not click on the button off, and instead settle close the tab or the browser? Forms that was built, he will remain logged in 20 min standards IIS defaults to downtime, but the expiration time of the cookie, not to mention that this way I will not be able to register DataDeSaida in LogDeAcesso.

Thinking about it I configured in the Web.config a timeout interval in the Session

### Web.Config

```
&ltconfiguration&gt
    &ltsystem.web&gt
        &ltcompilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" /&gt
        &lthttpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /&gt
        &ltglobalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" /&gt
        &ltauthentication mode="Forms"&gt
            &ltforms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" /&gt
        &lt/authentication&gt
        &ltsessionState
            mode="InProc"
            stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
            stateNetworkTimeout="20"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Integrated Security=SSPI"
            sqlCommandTimeout="20"
            customProvider=""
            cookieless="UseCookies"
            cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId"
            timeout="1"
            allowCustomSqlDatabase="false"
            regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
            partitionResolverType=""
            useHostingIdentity="true"&gt
            &ltproviders&gt
                &ltclear /&gt
            &lt/providers&gt
        &lt/sessionState&gt
        &ltmachineKey validationKey="466AFE06F664B2E3662F97B81D30E87907F9921E51C95C618A670B396403AD98DD032BCE7610EEAE1FB1DA7B3ED7ACE56537E66FD6DF20E701351697E57C3D9C" decryptionKey="CD10ABC11246E6998AB7B9A8CC142CDD6C8AEF7FB12D15CF12158BEAD647C603" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" /&gt 
    &lt/system.web&gt
&lt/configuration&gt
```

Only when the timeout happens and I get on the Global.asax    `Session_End()`    method, I can not access repositories and neither the `FormsAuthentication`.

I've tried to redirect the    `Session_End()`    to ActionResult Logoff using the following code

```
RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Account");
routeData.Values.Add("action", "Login");

IController AccountMainController = new AccountController();
AccountMainController.Execute(new RequestContext(
    new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), routeData));
```

However when passing through the line    `AccountMainController.Execute(new RequestContext (new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), RouteData)); throws an exception of type ArgumentNullException: "Value can not be null Parameter name: httpContext`.

I wonder what I have to do to repeat within the   `Session_End()`    exactly what I do by clicking the logoff button. Could anyone help?

Comment: I think you're seeing the inherent problems to trying to track things meant to be transient and stateless. I would take a different approach and track "Last Seen" instead of trying to track "Logged out". When a request is made update the "Last Seen" for the user. If they close the browser this date/time would be fairly accurate of when they left.

Comment: Could you show some code that could elucidate me about what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I concluded that it is impossible to perform "log off" in the same way that I perform when clicking the button in    `Session_End()`    , the way I arranged to clear the cookie, after the timeout event, was writing following code in    `Session_Start()`    .

```
    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        try
        {
            var usuario = new SessionContext().GetUserData();

            if (usuario == null) return;

            Session.Clear(); //Pode não ser necessário, mas não é problemático o uso como prevenção
            Session.Abandon();

            //Limpar o cookie de Autenticação
            var resetFormsCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
            resetFormsCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(resetFormsCookie);

            //Limpar a session cookie
            var resetSessionCookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
            resetSessionCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(resetSessionCookie);

            //Invalida o Cache no lado do Cliente
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            Response.RedirectToRoute("Default");
        }
    }
```

And as prevention, I wrote the following code in    `Session_End()`    .

```
    protected void Session_End()
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
    }
```